# Excel formulas to SQL

Tags: sql

I have this 3 Excel formulas to convert to SQL.

```
"E1335" =IF(D135=0,0,IF(AND(AU135/D135>=0.8,AU135/D135<1),1,ROUNDDOWN(AU135/D135,0)))
```

here Comes the Problem in SQL since in this part it links back to (E135) the 1. if calculation and just fail.

```
"F135" =IF(C135=0,0,IF(E135=1,0,ROUNDDOWN((AU135-E135*D135)/C135,0)))


"G135" =IF(B135=0,0,IF(E135=1,0,ROUNDDOWN((AU135-E135*D135-F135*C135)/B135,0)))




CASE WHEN [D135] = 0 THEN 0 

WHEN [AU135] / [D135] >= 0.8 AND [AU135] / [D135] < 1 THEN 1 

ELSE Floor ([AU135] / [D135]) 

END AS E135,

CASE WHEN [C135] = 0 OR E135 1 THEN 0 

ELSE Floor ([AU135] - [E135] * [D135] / [C135]) END AS [F135]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the equivalent in SQL:
The 1st:

```
CASE 
  WHEN [D135] = 0 THEN 0
  ELSE CASE
    WHEN [AU135] / [D135] >= 0.8 AND [AU135] / [D135] < 1 THEN 1
    ELSE FLOOR([AU135] / [D135]) 
  END
END
```

The 2nd:

```
CASE 
  WHEN [C135] = 0 THEN 0
  ELSE CASE
    WHEN [E135] = 1 THEN 0
    ELSE FLOOR(([AU135] - [E135] * [D135]) / [C135])
  END
END
```

The 3d:

```
CASE 
  WHEN [B135] = 0 THEN 0
  ELSE CASE
    WHEN [E135] = 1 THEN 0
    ELSE FLOOR(([AU135] - [E135] * [D135] - [F135] * [C135]) / [B135])
  END
END
```

Comment: Is it not a problem that in case 1 we created E135 (value) and then in case2 we just link it again to calculate with this new column?

Comment: SQL is not Excel. Each expression must be evaluated in a different statement.

Comment: So you mean that in 2nd part where I have E135 I just need to change it to the 1st code where we declare E135?

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. Of course there are tricks (maybe) that could make this easier depending on the requirement.